# How to display search results from two sources/web parts?

Tags: search-results

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I have created two people search pages. On one, I use the People Search Core Result web part to display user info and it is working. The only issue there is that I don't want to display "By username" column but I can't figure out how.

On my other search page, I use Search Core Results(Sortable) to display info from SAP. That is working as it should.

My question is how can I put these two web parts on the same page? When I do that, it only displays info from the People Search Core Result web part. From the SAP source, I get an error message that there is no match for the user I am searching for but I know that the user exists there. How to proceed?

Comment: I solved this by editing the Cross-Web query ID setting in my webparts, set one to "user query" and the other to "query 2" and my page is now displaying results from both webparts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by editing the Cross-Web Part query ID setting in my webparts, set one to "user query" and the other to "query 2" and my page is now displaying results from both webparts :)